# Magento2 tries to instantiate Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract

Tags: collection, magento2-dev-beta, factory

I've been playing with Magento 2 beta 1 and I'm trying to create a simple CRUD module for learning purposes.
I shamelessly cloned the `Magento_Cms` module into a module called `Sample_News`. The `Page` entity became the `Author` entity and I just added different fields to the author table.
everything works fine in the backend and in the frontend I can view the author's details page.
But now I tried something different that the `Magento_Cms` module does not have.  I try to list in a page all my available entity instances (all the authors in this case).
For this I looked for inspiration in the `Magento_Sales` module in the orders history block.
But I get an error. For some reason Magento is trying to instantiate the `Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract` class and I get this error when trying to create an instance of a collection model:

> Missing required argument $config of Zend_Db_Adapter_Abstract.

Here is some code I have.

The block that is causing the error:

```
<?php
namespace Sample\News\Block\Author;

use Sample\News\Model\Resource\Author\CollectionFactory;
use Magento\Framework\UrlFactory;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template;
use Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context;

class ListAuthor extends Template {
    protected $authorCollectionFactory;
    protected $urlFactory;
    public function __construct(
        Context $context,
        CollectionFactory $authorCollectionFactory,
        UrlFactory $urlFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->authorCollectionFactory = $authorCollectionFactory;
        $this->urlFactory = $urlFactory;
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
    }

    protected  function _construct() {
        parent::_construct();
        //this crashes `$this->authorCollectionFactory->create()`
        $authors = $this->authorCollectionFactory->create()->addFieldToSelect('*')
            ->addFieldToFilter('is_active', 1)
            ->addStoreFilter($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId())
            ->setOrder('name','desc');
        $this->setAuthors($authors);
    }
    protected function _prepareLayout() {
        parent::_prepareLayout();
        $pager = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Pager', 'sample_news.author.list.pager')
            ->setCollection($this->getAuthors());
        $this->setChild('pager', $pager);
        $this->getAuthors()->load();
        return $this;
    }
    public function getPagerHtml() 
    {
        return $this->getChildHtml('pager');
    }
}
```

The controller action class. Nothing fancy here. Just load the layout and render it.

```
<?php
namespace Sample\News\Controller\Author;

class Index extends \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action
{
    protected $resultPageFactory;
    protected $coreRegistry;
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Framework\View\Result\PageFactory $resultPageFactory
    )
    {
        $this->resultPageFactory = $resultPageFactory;
        parent::__construct($context);
    }
    public function execute()
    {
        $resultPage = $this->resultPageFactory->create();
        $resultPage->getConfig()->getTitle()->set('Authors');
        return $resultPage;
    }
}
```

The collection factory class is autogenerated and the collection class looks like this:

```
<?php
namespace Sample\News\Model\Resource\Author;

use Magento\Framework\Data\AbstractSearchResult;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Collection\EntityFactoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\SearchResultIteratorFactory;
use Magento\Framework\DB\QueryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ManagerInterface;
use Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Data\SearchResultProcessorFactory;
use Magento\Framework\Data\SearchResultProcessor;

class Collection extends \Magento\Framework\Data\AbstractSearchResult
{
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $searchResultProcessor;

    public function __construct(
        QueryInterface $query,
        EntityFactoryInterface $entityFactory,
        ManagerInterface $eventManager,
        SearchResultIteratorFactory $resultIteratorFactory,
        StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        SearchResultProcessorFactory $searchResultProcessorFactory
    ) {
        $this->storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->searchResultProcessor = $searchResultProcessorFactory->create($this);
        parent::__construct($query, $entityFactory, $eventManager, $resultIteratorFactory);
    }

    protected function init()
    {
        $this->setDataInterfaceName('Sample\News\Model\Author');
        $this->query->addCountSqlSkipPart(\Zend_Db_Select::GROUP, true);
        $this->storeTableName = 'sample_news_author';
        $this->linkFieldName = 'author_id';
    }
}
```

Any pointers will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not near a computer just now, but have a look at the DI.xml files. Maybe there is a dependency on the interface (which is good) without a preference specifying the real class to instantiate?

It is common to depend on interfaces (for loose coupling) with the DI.xml files plugging in the real classes to use, making it easier to swap in different implementations. Check the DI.xml files for the modules you copied from.

Comment: I don't think I forgot something, but I checked anyway and realized something. There is a difference between the `Magento_Cms` module (the one I sort of cloned) and `Magento_Sales` (the one I used as inspiration for the list). The Cms module uses a `PageCriteria` resource model to retrieve the pages and list them on the backend. the sales module does not have this. It just has a simple collection that extends `\Magento\Framework\Model\Resource\Db\Collection\AbstractCollection`. I should try to use the same `PageCriteria` resource model on frontend also. (1/2)

Comment: (2/2) This looks like an inconsistency to me. I think that all CRUD modules should have a common behavior. They used to have it (sort of) in Magento 1. I guess that not everything is refactored yet.  I found a few other differences in like this one between modules. But this is a totally different thing. I will post a question about these differences and the common behavior of the modules on github in the next days. In the mean time, thanks for the answer. I'm not sure yet that the DI.xml is the problem but  it helped me look in the right place and see the flaw in my  approach.

Comment: You are right that not everything refactored yet. If there is an Api directory that is likely to be newer. Plan is to end up with ORM style model, but thinking about how to get there (and whether that is the right fit for Magento with extensible attributes etc).

Comment: After further investigation, it seams that I was using this wrong. I was trying to combine 2 different approaches into one but they are not compatible. Even if this answer did not solve my problem, it put me on the right track. Thanks.